# Create hyperlinks to all non empty cells in range - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Range A10 and down contains some non empty cells.

1. Need macro to populate range `G6:U7` with hyperlinks to non empty cells in range `A10` and down.
2. Hyperlinks to display contents of those cells, and fill that range left to right, then to next row.
3. Any extras to populate to range `V6:Z7`

e.g. picture below:

[image: A10 & down + hyperlinks]

Not sure how to accomplish this

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InsertHyperlinksToSheet1()
    InsertHyperlinks ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Sub

Public Sub InsertHyperlinksToSheet2()
    InsertHyperlinks ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
End Sub

Public Sub InsertHyperlinks(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim firstRow As Long: firstRow = 6
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = 7
    Dim firstCol As String: firstCol = "G"
    Dim lastCol As String: lastCol = "U"
    Dim firstExtraCol As String: firstExtraCol = "V"
    Dim lastExtraCol As String: lastExtraCol = "Z"
    Dim current As Range: Set current = ws.Cells(firstRow, firstCol)
    Dim r As Long: For r = 10 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim source As Range: Set source = ws.Cells(r, 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(source.Value) Then
            If current Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print "Out of space for links"
                Exit For
            Else
                current.Value = source.Value
                ws.Hyperlinks.Add current, "", ws.Name & "!" & source.Address(False, False)
                Dim currentCol As String: currentCol = Split(current.EntireColumn.Address(False, False), ":")(0)
                If (firstCol <= currentCol And currentCol < lastCol) _
                Or (firstExtraCol <= currentCol And currentCol < lastExtraCol) Then
                    Set current = current.Offset(0, 1)
                ElseIf current.Row < lastRow Then
                    Set current = current.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Cells(1, IIf(currentCol < firstExtraCol, firstCol, firstExtraCol))
                ElseIf current.Row = lastRow And currentCol = lastCol Then
                    Set current = ws.Cells(firstRow, firstExtraCol)
                Else
                    Set current = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Update 1**: Modified the code to spill over to `V6:Z7`. (Though I don't really see why that was good.)

**Update 2**: Refactored the code to demonstrate how to reuse it (how to call it from multiple functions).

Comment: Thanks, seems to work, but once it runs out of destination space it does not use the additional destination space for a spillover.  I'll test the second answer below to see which works best.

Comment: What additional destination space do you mean?

Comment: Point 3 of my original post:
Any extras to populate to range V6:Z7

Comment: Meanwhile I've updated the code. Does it work now as you wanted?

Comment: How do I modify the below line, so that the code will simply run on whatever sheet is active, instead of restricting it to a specific sheet? Is this the only line I'd have to change, and how? Line in question: Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Comment: Yes, that's the only line you have to change. Actually, that's the purpose of it: you have to modify it only at one place, and the code stays consistent. You can change it to Sheet2 with `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")` or to the active sheet with `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Thanks, but say if I copy the worksheet into the same workbook and I want to run same functionality on the new worksheet, sounds like I'd have to duplicate this entire code into a separate sub and change all the references of ws to ws2, right?  And change the button on the new worksheet to call the new sub?

Comment: I've updated my answer but I'm not sure if this a bad joke, or you actually can't do such basic things yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all code in the sheets's module, but if you want
the function "getNonBlankCells" can move in a library module for common use.

```
Option Explicit

Sub tester()
   ' call the sub with three arguments:
   ' 1. the cell to look after in it's column for non empty cells
   ' 2. The first destination area to create the links
   ' 3. The second destination area to create the links
   Call makeHLNK(Me.Range("A10"), Me.Range("G6:U7"), Me.Range("V6:Z7"))
End Sub

Sub makeHLNK(lookAfter As Range, desta As Range, destb As Range)
   Dim notEmpty As Range, cl As Range, destaCnt As Long, destbCnt As Long
   Dim c As Long, lastRow As Long, maxLnks As Long, cc As Long
   
   ' create destination range for links
   With lookAfter
      ' find last non empty row
      lastRow = Me.Cells(Me.rows.CountLarge, .Column).End(xlUp).row
      ' if lastRow < row of staring cell => nothing to do
      If lastRow < .row Then Exit Sub
      ' create the range using lastRow
      'Set notEmpty = .Resize(lastRow - .row + 1, 1)
      ' use a helper function to get only non empty cells
      Set notEmpty = getNonBlankCells(.Resize(lastRow - .row + 1, 1))
   End With
   ' if don't have filled cells => nothing to do
   If notEmpty Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   ' max links to create is the MIN of: not empty cells and destination (link) cells
   destaCnt = desta.CountLarge
   destbCnt = destb.CountLarge
   maxLnks = IIf(notEmpty.CountLarge <= destaCnt + destbCnt, notEmpty.CountLarge, destaCnt + destbCnt)
   If maxLnks < notEmpty.CountLarge Then
      MsgBox ("No space for more " & notEmpty.CountLarge - maxLnks & " links.")
   End If
   For Each cl In notEmpty
      c = c + 1
      cc = cc + 1
      ' make links as many as the holding positions / no more
      If cc > maxLnks Then
         Exit For
      End If
      ' use the second area for links if it exceeds 
      ' the limits of the first
      If cc = destaCnt + 1 Then
         Set desta = destb
         c = 1
      End If
      desta(c).value = cl.value
      Me.Hyperlinks.Add desta(c), "", "'" & Me.Name & "'!" & cl.Address(0, 0)
   Next
End Sub


' A HELPER FUNCTION TO RETURN NON EMPTY CELLS OF RANGE
Public Function getNonBlankCells(r As Range) As Range
    Dim cnst As Range, frml As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set cnst = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set frml = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not cnst Is Nothing Then
      If Not frml Is Nothing Then
         Set getNonBlankCells = Union(cnst, frml)
      Else
         Set getNonBlankCells = cnst
      End If
    ElseIf Not frml Is Nothing Then
      Set getNonBlankCells = frml
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but code gives the Compile error "Invalid use of Me keyword" on first Me in:
Call makeHLNK(Me.Range("A10"), Me.Range("G6:U7", "V6:Z7"))

Comment: @Cap'n Crunch  Please read carefully, I wrote: "Copy all code in the sheet's module".  So, try to copy the code NOT in a "library" module, but in the module of the sheet.

Comment: Thanks, now it does not give errors, but it also does not ignore the empty cells in source column, i.e. it generates the links for empty cells as well as non empty. Whereas needs to ignore the empty cells -- just like on the illustration I have in my original post above.

Comment: The code tested before post it here, maybe your cells are not empty... but have spaces... or other non printable characters.

Comment: i recheck it now.. everything may happen in coding...

Comment: @Cap'n Crunch, can you try that again? I modified the loop before Me.Hyperlinks.Add... I had checked it with filled OR empty cells but grouped all together the: For c=1 to ... doesn't work on discontinuous ranges. Now using the For ... each works as it should.

Comment: After the last modification it uses the Link areas correctly, fills first the first one and then the second. Another thing I hadn't noticed is that these two areas are contiguous...

Comment: Thanks, but now getting "Reference isn't valid", when clicking on hyperlinks in either of the two destination ranges.

Comment: This is because the sheet name has spaces or starts with a number. I fixed a line by enclosing the name of the sheet in the generated links with single quotes.